# Product Configurator in magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript

I want to create a module for customized t-shirts design. Configurator modules consist following features:

- Product Image upload
- Text configuration on production
- Size
- Colors

For size and color, I can simply use configurable products default functionality of magento.
But by this module I want to be able to upload logo or any custom image to be applied on t-shirt and also want to have option to write text (option to choose text font and color).

Can any one suggest me the way how can I start on it (by adopting which PHP library and javascript library, I can do this. I am comfortable with creating custom module in magento.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are looking for product configurator for Magento 2 then here is the one

https://www.codedecorator.com/magento-2-product-configurator.html